# Script Calls Wrong echo

Tags: php

I am trying to return data from my database. The query will return a zero or one. If the data returns one (`if psv1=1`) I want to echo 'Data found'. If the data returns a zero (`if psv1=0`) I want to echo 'No data found'.

When I run my script I always get 'No data found', even when `psv1=1`. I also tried to change `$res[0] == 1` to `$res[0] > 0` but it didn't work.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_handle, 'SELECT psv1 FROM cus WHERE id="1" AND user_id="'. $_SESSION['user_id'] .'"');
$res = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

if ($res[0] == 1){
    echo 'Data found';  
}
else
{
echo "No data found";
}
```

Comment: You realize that you need to fetch the data before you can compare it, right?

Comment: You are not comparing `psv1` you are comparing number of rows

Comment: You are right. I changed It. But now I always get "No data found"

Comment: `print_r($res)` you will see the real values

Comment: print_r($res) = prints empty

Comment: then there are no results

Comment: `print_r($res)` doesn't print anything because `$res` is `FALSE` (you can use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to be sure). This means the query is incorrect or `$db_handle` is not a valid MySQLi connection.

Comment: if you test whether $result === FALSE, then there very well may be an error in the actual query statement.

Comment: Are you looking for psv in your query as you say in the question? As far as I can see you are looking for id instead of psv

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Manual](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_row), mysqli_fetch_row() will return NULL on failure or else an array of strings corresponding to a row of data as an enumerated array.  I suggest also testing that mysqli_query() does not return FALSE as per the Manual's recommendation by way of numerous examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). So, a better test would be to code something like the following with $query having been set to the specific query:

```
<?php

$result = null;
$res = null;

$result = mysqli_query( $db_handle, $query ) OR die( mysqli_error( $db_handle ));

if( ( $res = mysqli_fetch_row( $result )) === NULL ) {
     // Nothing to fetch
}        
else 
{
     echo ($res[0] == 1 )? "Data found." : "No data found";
}
```

Comment: Why is `foreach` needed when the query is fired for `id` and `user_id`? Also, why redundant if-else. It can easily be avoided.

Comment: Dude, are you kidding me.. In that case, you should also check `$_SESSION['user_id']` variable is `not-a-string` and is a positive integer and is with length < 10, etc. If those checks are not met, why even fire a query, right?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you need both conditions in the WHERE. Are you meaning to have id and user_id. Suggest removing:

```
id="1" AND
```

Can only be a guess, but seems unlikely condition.

On checking no results returned, may I suggest trying:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_handle, 'SELECT psv1 FROM cus WHERE id="1" 
AND user_id="'. $_SESSION['user_id'] .'"');

$res = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 

echo 'Data found'; 

}

else {

echo "No data found";

}
```

[See related SO answer on mysqli_num_rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063068/how-to-check-if-mysql-query-return-no-resultrecord-not-found-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_handle, 'SELECT psv1 FROM cus WHERE id="1" AND user_id="'. $_SESSION['user_id'] .'"');
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if ($res['psv1'] == 1){
    echo 'Data found';  
}
else {
    echo "No data found";
}
```

Comment: @slevy1 - Please elaborate.

Comment: Well, the objective is to check if the `psv1` has value == 1 or not. So instead of checking for NULL or ZERO or anything, straight forward, we should check for 1.

Comment: Alright, I updated it. And secondly, if the query is failing, it should rather be an exception and/or should be handled by the framework. Rather have `try-catch` for it. One cannot really have a check for every query in the application that he/she is building. There should be a query-wrapper that which ideally every framework does have. Hence, having that check doesn't make sense.