# php mail sending when nothing to be sent

Tags: php, mysqli

The php below is run from a cronjob each night. BUT it is still sending mail despite having nothing to send. 
So, if the $initialsearch is empty then no mail should be send. I have tried different methods to stop this from reversing my if statement at the end to trying to count the rows from the initialsearch but every time its sending a mail. 
So i only want this script to send a mail if the $initialseach contains a result else do nothing.

```
<?php
include ('adbfile.php');

$to = "me.mail.com";
$subject = "Device Alert";
$subject .= date("H:i:s d:M:Y");
$from = "this.mail.com";
$message = '';  // start with empty string
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$initialsearch = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM mydevices where devicename like '123%' and Level = 0");

$message .='';
$message .= '<html><body>';
$message .='<h1 style="color:#f66;"Device Alert.</h1>';

//$id is previously defined as the users id 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($initialsearch))
{
     $devicename = $row['DeviceName'];
     $devicenumber = $row['DeviceNumber'];
     $devicelevel = $row['DeviceLevel'];

$message .= '<p style="color:#f80;">'.$devicename.' '.$devicenumber.' '.$devicelevel.'</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
}
$message .= 'device alert system.';

if (empty($initialsearch)) {
    echo ("There is nothing to send");
} else {
    (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers));
}
?>
```

The last if statement i have change numerous times and done in different ways but nothing has worked so far. Any help appreciated.

Comment: what is the data type of `$initialsearch use echo gettype($initialsearch);`

Comment: `$initialsearch` will never be empty because it gets the return of `mysqli_query` For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, or EXPLAIN queries it will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries it will return TRUE. FALSE on failure.

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063068/how-to-check-if-mysql-query-return-no-resultrecord-not-found-using-php

Comment: use simple mail  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)  without  bracket  or check above condition if its working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to check for empty result:

```
$initialsearch = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM mydevices ....");

// check for empty result
if (mysqli_num_rows($initialsearch) == 0) {
    echo ("There is nothing to send");
} else {
    ....

    // while loop to get results
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($initialsearch)) {
         ....
    }

    // send email
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli_query` returns one of the mixed data type.
So having `empty($initialsearch`) might not return an empty data type value.

rather you could try an if statement as follows:

declare your variable `$devicename = NULL` above the `while` loop.

```
if($devicename === NULL)
```

Haven't tried it yet, let me know if it works out.

Comment: this did also work for me however php threw a warning :-

 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: devicename in /mail.php on line 33

Comment: I have edited my answer. However, the above answer seems to work better for you!